# How to apply for a UAE visa (Dubai) for my 16th year-old sister?

Tags: air-travel, tourist-visas, dubai, uae, minors

Information:

Our parents are not travelling with us but I'm 18 now, so it would help?

Sister is 16 years old.

It would be helpful because our real sister is living over there and they also have PR (permanent residency). So she could give NOC or sponsor us.

Comment: She can apply for your visas directly from UAE and email them to you. That's the fastest and easiest way

Comment: Your sister needs a UAE visa or you need the visa to visit her in the UAE? Please clarify this.